# Undrawn straight lines

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 to fill entire iPad Retina screen with points. The code is very simple:

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO);
glPointSize(1);
glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
int ww = 1024, hh = 768;
for (int i = 0; i < ww * hh; ++i) {
  [self extendVertexBuffer:vertexCount];
  int xx = i % ww, yy = i / ww;
  vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = xx;
  vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = yy;
  ++vertexCount;
}
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);
```

In result while running this code on iPad all view is white except 2 lines: horizontal with Y = 23 and vertical with X = 31. glReadPixels confirms that these lines have default color.

Some trick is using glPointSize(2), but I suspect better decision should exists.

Interesting detail - running the code on Simulator doesn't get this effect.

Will be glad to see any ideas to solve this strange issue.

P.S. Do not propose to draw triangles, I really need to draw points. Listed code is just very simplified part of more complex function.

Comment: As a start rendering `1024*768 = 786432 points` is really bad. Really a waste. Also don't update the buffer each time... You could try rendering to a Texture and them simply render a huge quad with the texture on. Thereby you could also have a smaller texture, but without gaps in the image, AND DON'T UPDATE THE TEXTURE AT EACH RENDER, only update the texture when needed... An even better idea, would be to look into something else than rendering individual points, not good man, not good... Also, you should really look into some modern OpenGL...

Comment: This is just a simple code to describe a problem. In fact, the filling area is smaller, rendering executes just once and it is saved as a texture. But the problem is still here - framebuffer contains unfilled points.

Comment: If it's only done once. Then use the texture idea I just gave you. This way you can easily with precision change each pixel, and you're guaranteed that "the points are filled".